# hibernate cannot open JDBC Connection after few calls

Tags: spring, hibernate, jdbc, jdbctemplate, hibernate-criteria

I am new to hibernate and trying to use it, so for learning purpose some where I am using Criteria API and some where HQL.

My application is running fine but problem is after executing 5-6 times, no more JDBC connection get opened and application hangs there.

in logs it says...Opening JDBC Connection......thats it.

I read few docs and it says this is because of not releasing Session once it is opened.

This is the functions I am running.

```
    public List<Place> getAllPlaces() {

        Session session = getSession();
        Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(Place.class);
        List ls= cr.list();

        session.close();

        return ls;

    }


    public List<User> getAllUser() {

        Session session = getSession();
        Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(User.class);
        List ls= cr.list();

        session.close();

        return ls;
    }

    public List<Carpooler> getAllCarpooler() {

        Session session = getSession();
        Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(Carpooler.class);
        List ls= cr.list();

        session.close();

        return ls;

    }

    public List<SourceToDestinationDetails> getAllSourceToDestinationDetailsbyCarpooler(
            Carpooler carpooler) {

        Session session = getSession();
        Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(SourceToDestinationDetails.class);
        cr.add(Expression.eq("listOfSourceToDestinationDetails",carpooler));
        List ls= cr.list();

        session.close();

        return ls;
    }

    public List<Carpooler> getExactMatchCarpooler(String from, String to) {

        log.debug("Request received for fetching Exact match Carpooler.");

        List<Carpooler> listOfFinalCarpooler = new ArrayList<Carpooler>();

        List list = null;
        try{
            list = getHibernateTemplate().findByNamedQueryAndNamedParam("findExactMatchingCarpooler", new String[]{"source","destination"}, new String[]{from,to});

            if(list!=null){
                log.debug("Fetched Exact match carpooler list is :"+list.toString());

                for (int j = 0; j < list.size(); j++) {
                    Object[] l = (Object[])list.get(j);

                        Carpooler c = (Carpooler)l[0];
                        SourceToDestinationDetails std = (SourceToDestinationDetails)l[1];

                        Carpooler c1 = new Carpooler();
                        c1.setCarpoolerCreationDate(c.getCarpoolerCreationDate());
                        c1.setCarpoolerId(c.getCarpoolerId());
                        c1.setDrivingLicenceNumber(c.getDrivingLicenceNumber());
                        c1.setUser(c.getUser());
                        c1.setListOfVehicleDetails(c.getListOfVehicleDetails());
                        c1.setUserType(c.getUserType());

                        List<SourceToDestinationDetails> listOfSourceToDestinationDetails =new ArrayList<SourceToDestinationDetails>();
                        listOfSourceToDestinationDetails.add(std);

                        c1.setListOfSourceToDestinationDetails(listOfSourceToDestinationDetails);

                        listOfFinalCarpooler.add(c1);

//                      log.debug("Carpooler is :"+c.getCarpoolerId());
//                      log.debug("SourceToDestinationDetails is :"+std.getSourceToDestinationId());
                }


            }else{
                log.debug("List is null");
            }



        log.debug("Returning back from fetching Exact match Carpooler");

            return listOfFinalCarpooler;
        }catch(Exception e){
            log.error("Exception Occurred while fetching Exact Match Result :"+e.getMessage());
        }
    return null;    
}
```

Logs

```
2012-12-28 10:32:33,529 DEBUG http-8080-4 [DashboardController.getLoginPage1] - Fetching list of all user, to display count on home page.
2012-12-28 10:32:33,529 DEBUG http-8080-4 [SessionFactoryUtils.doGetSession] - Opening Hibernate Session
2012-12-28 10:32:33,530 DEBUG http-8080-4 [SessionImpl.<init>] - opened session at timestamp: 13566709535
2012-12-28 10:32:33,531 DEBUG http-8080-4 [AbstractBatcher.logOpenPreparedStatement] - about to open PreparedStatement (open PreparedStatements: 0, globally: 0)
2012-12-28 10:32:33,531 DEBUG http-8080-4 [ConnectionManager.openConnection] - opening JDBC connection
```

Can someone please guide me where I am going wrong.

Comment: Are all those criteria queries working fine, or are there any exceptions being thrown? Did you debug to see if the session.close() method actually gets called?

Comment: I dont think so, because in logs I am getting as , 

2012-12-28 10:32:33,462 DEBUG http-8080-4 [ConnectionManager.afterTransaction] - transaction completed on session with on_close connection release mode; be sure to close the session to release JDBC resources! ,  

So what step i should follow to close it correctly.

Comment: Don't deal with the session directly use Transaction layer for the safest DB calls ..

Comment: can you please point out some code snippet for reference or some links if possible...

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to get the session using [HibernateDaoSupport.getSession()](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/support/HibernateDaoSupport.html#getSession%28%29) method.

API Says,

> Note that this is not meant to be invoked from HibernateTemplate code
>   but rather just in plain Hibernate code. Either rely on a thread-bound
>   Session or use it in combination
>   withreleaseSession(org.hibernate.Session).

So use [HibernateDaoSupport.releaseSession(org.hibernate.Session)](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/support/HibernateDaoSupport.html#releaseSession%28org.hibernate.Session%29) method as below to close the open sessions instead of `session.close()`.

```
releaseSession(session);
```